# In exwm (Emacs X Window Manager) how can I switch to the workspace where a given app resides?

Tags: exwm

I'm using `exwm-workspace-switch-to-buffer` to find already opened applications. My problem is, say I'm in workspace 1, and Firefox is open in workspace 3, if I call `exwm-workspace-switch-to-buffer` for Firefox, `exwm` brings Firefox to workspace 1 but I want it to shoot me to workspace 3 where Firefox resides and leave the workspace 1 intact. In `i3wm` I can do this by something like `for_window [class="(?i)firefox"] focus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the owner of `exwm` this is no longer an issue. See [this issue](https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/issues/261#issuecomment-304930885).

Answer (score 1):

The command to do that is `exwm-workspace-switch-to-buffer` and it requires `exwm-layout-show-all-buffers` to be `nil`. With an appropriate font-face or theme workspaces with X-windows will be highlighted.